# Android running Intent Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I'm creating an android application that will do a simple task in a specific time (defined by the user). For this I'm using an Intent Service because after the task is done, then the service can terminate.

The problem is if the user closes the application (example: using back button) then I cannot get the running service (Intent Service). When the application starts again, and if it's already running my service, I would like to get information from it, using BroadcastReceiver (to update my activity), or to shutdown it.

What is the best way to achive this? Is there a better approach?

Thanks
jpaulino

Comment: **"...do a simple task..."** : What is your 'simple task'?

Comment: It's a timer that is working already using a scheduleTaskExecutor ... I want to do change the audio profile (AudioManager) after x minutes and without a service when the application closes, the timer/thread, ends.